# Confusion in Hoffman and Kunze, page-31

Tags: linear-algebra

I was revising vector spaces from Hoffman and Kunze, and I came across the following from the second chapter:

[image: 0]

[image: 1]

I understand that the same set of vectors may be part of a number of distinct vector spaces; for example, $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$, as we see in the first sentence of example $5$.

But I don't understand after *"More generally"*; how the example given is different from the space $\mathbb{C}^n$. Since the elements $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ of vector $\alpha$ are complex numbers, it is different from the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (over $\mathbb{R}$). But why will be different from the space $\mathbb{C}^n$?

And by *"the space $\mathbb{C}^n$"*, do they mean $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: They're considering three spaces, $\Bbb C^n$ *over* $\Bbb C$, $\Bbb R^n$ *over* $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C^n$ *over* $\Bbb R$.  Three different vector spaces.

Comment: The first part of example 5 shows that $\mathbb{C}$ can be "the same set of vectors" in two different vector spaces.  That is, $\mathbb{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ (of dimension $1$) and also a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (of dimension $2$).  This is the sort of idea of "same set of vectors" and "different vector spaces" being generalized.  Note that $V$ in example 5 is a *subset* of $\mathbb{C}^n$, but being presented as having structure of a real vector space (vector space over the field of real numbers).

Comment: $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ has infinite dimension. This is another example, maybe interesting for you.

Comment: @hardmath So, by the vector space $V$ in example $5$, they mean the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and by *"the space $\mathbb{C}^n$"* they mean $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$, and $V$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ (not subspace, as field is different)

Comment: Yes, as I read it, $V$ is the same set of things as $\mathbb{C}^n$, but using the field $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$ for scalar operations.  I'd have to fetch my copy of Hoffman and Kunze to be sure what Example 1 really said, but it illustrates the point for which Example 5 was cited.

Answer (score 1):

*Just summarizing the comments to take this question off the unanswered list.*

---

By "the space $C^n$" the authors mean the vector space $C^n$ over the field $C$, and by "the space $R^n$" the authors mean the vector space $R^n$ over the field $R$.

Usually, when $F$ is a field and one talks about the (vector) space $F^n$, one refers to the vector space $F^n$ over $F$ defined as in Example 1 (that is, with addition and scalar multiplication defined coordinate-wise). In Example 5, a different vector space is constructed, namely $C^n$ over $R$, which is not of the form $F^n$ over $F$.